# How Linq query fetch data from multiple tables without using join

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 tables in my database which have no relation with each other. what i want is to implement the search operation on my website. So that when a word is submit in search box the query go through all the tables and fetch the data wherever it find that word. I can fetch the data from single table.

```
    public ActionResult Searchresult(string searchString)
    {
        var article = (from c in db.Tbl_Article select c );
        article = article.Where(s => s.Article_Title.Contains(searchString));

        var blog = (from c in db.Tbl_Blog select c );
        blog = blog.Where(s => s.Blog_Title.Contains(searchString));

        var history = (from c in db.Tbl_History select c);
        history = history.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));

        var result = article.Select(x => x.Article_Title).Union(blog.Select(x => x.Blog_Title)).Union(history.Select(x => x.Title)).ToList();

    //  ViewBag.result = result.ToString();

        return View(result);
    }
```

Please don't confuse about what i return in action method, its a very long and unnecessary code for that question.

By using this code I successfully get the search result from one table.
Now I want same result from all the tables present in the database. that's where I'm stuck. I searched so many article for that but didn't find any solution that's in the last I myself asking this.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you do a join? You don't actually need a foreign key relationship between the tables, you can join on any arbitrary matching values.

Comment: @Clint I cant use join as there is no relationship between those tables. if anyhow i can use it please tell me.  thank you

Comment: What you're asking for isn't particularly possible, certainly not for all tables, as you need to know what columns you're searching over ahead of time.

Have you considered writing a stored procedure to do this for you?

If you're interested in doing it over certain tables (no matter how many), and you are prepared for it to be a fair bit of code, let me know and I may be able to get something more comprehensive together for you.

Comment: @Clint yeah sure, any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```
   Public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
     var query1 = (from c in db.TableArticle select c);
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
         {
    query1 = query1.Where(s => 
            s.Article_Title.Contains(searchString)
    || s.Article_Description.Contains(searchString) || 
             s.Written_By.Contains(searchString) || 
             s.Organisation.Contains(searchString)
   ||s.Source.Contains(searchString));
            }
    var query2 = (.......);
    var query3 = (.......);

    var finalResult = query1.Select(x => x.columnName).Union(query2.Select(x => x.columnName)).Union(query3.Select(x => x.columnName));
    // OR
    var finalResult = query1.Select(x => x.columnName).Concat(query2.Select(x => x.columnName)).Concat(query3.Select(x => x.columnName));
    }
```

Comment: i tried your code and getting this error :

CS1929 C# does not contain a definition for and the best extension method overload requires a receiver of type

Comment: Hi @inżynierumair , Can you please share in more detail what exactly you  want and  which error you got .

Comment: @ILYASPATEL I simply want a Linq query which can perform search operation. the data must be fetch from all the tables which are present in database and display in the search result. I used above answer but in line var final result = query1.concat or query1.union , got the above error.

Comment: @inżynierumair, I have just checked in my local and its working fine I have given answer hope it will helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

I have just implemented and checked in my local same query, and it's working fine, 
The given answer is right by @Khairul Alam,

I have just optimized the code and run the same thing in my local its working fine

```
var searchString = "School";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            var query1 = _context.Jobs.Where(s =>
                     s.JobTitle.Contains(searchString)
             || s.LocationDescription.Contains(searchString));

            var query2 = _context.Recruiters.Where(s =>
                    s.RecruiterName.Contains(searchString));

            var query3 = _context.Sectors.Where(s =>
                    s.SectorName.Contains(searchString));
            try
            {
                var finalResult = query1.Select(x => x.JobTitle).Union(query2.Select(x => x.RecruiterName)).Union(query3.Select(x => x.SectorName)).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

contain image which output of final result

[image: Click here for Final output]

If you still getting an issue , please share some code or where exactly you getting the error , so we can solve them

hope this will be helpful to you

Thanks

Comment: Thank you sir for the help,I updated my code, I got the result in my actionmethod, now im not able to show that result in my view. I mean which model item i need pass at the top of the view , so that  "something like:@foreach(var item in Model)" read the result